# How to simulate mouse scrolling

Tags: scroll, vbscript

I am working on a project, I would like help to simulate values ​in mouse scrolling, a path that I have been researching is this.

```
Set WX = CreateObject("DynamicWrapperX")
     
WX.Register "user32.dll", "GetActiveWindow", "r=l"
WX.Register "user32.dll", "PostMessageA", "i=hlll", "f=s", "r=l"
WX.Register "user32.dll", "ShowScrollBar", "i=hlp" 
    
WX.Register "user32.dll", "SetScrollPos", "i=hlll" 
     
WX.ShowScrollBar WX.GetActiveWindow(), 3, "1" 
WX.SetScrollPos 0, 1, 100000, 1
WX.PostMessageA WX.GetActiveWindow(), 277, 4 + 65536 * 100, 0
```

I got something using dynamicwrapperx, but the code creates a new scroll, and that's not what I need

Comment: What is your question? Is this code not behaving as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using DynamicWrapperX.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set WX = CreateObject("DynamicWrapperX")    
    WX.Register "user32.dll", "mouse_event", "i=uuulu", "f=s"
    WX.mouse_event 2048, 0, 0, -10, 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VBScript is really the scripting language you want to use to do that.  Something like AutoHotKey is probably better suited to that.

https://www.autohotkey.com/

AutoHotKey is a lot more flexible when it comes to controlling things on screen in a Windows environment.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm  <-- this one shows you how to send keyboard commands that can potentially control a window's scroll bar.  In this case, you'd want to send tabs to move over to the scroll bar (assuming you have an empty Notepad window) and then press the down arrow key.

Please note also, in your VBScript example above, you have misspelled Notepad.  That's probably causing you some problems trying get the script to do anything.

Comment: I do not have this option, I am working with an Elipse E3 supervisory creation ide, and it only makes use of VBScript, so I need something in this regard.

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502385/vbscript-getting-application-window-text and try using sendkeys once you get the window handle?  Then just mimic keyboard entries.